# Yii's rule about date not working

Tags: php, validation, yii

My Yii's version: 1.1.13.

I am using two rules for the same field.

```
    public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('data_preenchimento', 'required'),
            array('data_preenchimento', 'type', 'type'=>'date', 'dateFormat'=>'dd/MM/yy'),
```

When the element lose the focus, if it's empty, the 'required' rule can be seen in action. But if its value is anything different from the format rule, like "894089095" for example, nothing happens.

I've also tried to change the format rule to these:

```
array('data_preenchimento', 'type', 'type'=>'date', 'message'=>'the date is not valid.', 'dateFormat'=>'dd/MM/yy'),
```

and

```
array('data_preenchimento', 'date', 'format'=>'dd/MM/yy'),
```

---

Note: the widget have these properties set to true:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'questionario-form',
    'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('//questionario/index'),
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        'validateOnChange'=>true,
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
));
```

---

Update: below is my `rules()`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('pais_de_origem,data_preenchimento,conhecimento_regiao,motivos_visita,aspectos_interesse,vim_de,vou_para', 'required'),
        array('data_preenchimento', 'date', 'format'=>'dd/MM/yyyy', 'message'=>'A data deve ter o formato dd/mm/aaaa.', 'allowEmpty'=>false),
        array('motivos_visita', 'verificarLimiteDeMotivosDaVisita'),
        array('aspectos_interesse', 'verificarLimiteDeAspectosDeInteresse'),
        array('quais_conhecimento_regiao', 'verificarQuaisConhecimentoDaRegiao'),
        array('quais_motivos_visita', 'verificarQuaisMotivosDaVisita'),
        array('quais_aspectos_interesse', 'verificarQuaisAspectosDeInteresse'),
        array('quais_factores', 'verificarQuaisFactores'),
        array('factores_outros,sites_conhecimento_regiao,facilidade_conhecimento_regiao', 'safe'),
    );
}
```

---

Why can't Yii use the rule in this case? How can I fix it?

Comment: In the action in the controller do you have `$this->performAjaxValidation($model);` ?

Comment: @Pitchinnate No, but is it needed? If yes, why does a date validation require Ajax?

Comment: If you want to validate it upon losing focus on an element it does the validation with Ajax. Try submitting your form now with the incorrect date format does the rule work then?

Comment: @Pitchinnate It doesn't work nor when I submit the form. But I'll try it with Ajax so.

Comment: Is the `required` rule working correctly? What happens if you leave the field blank?

Comment: Yes, `required` is OK. When I leave any field blank the validation use the default message... [field] cannot be blank.

Comment: Which widget do you have `enableClientValidation` on? In input field or the form?

Comment: @Pitchinnate I answered you updating the question.

Comment: What scenario is your instance of your model set to? Can you post your entire `rules` array? You can get the scenario by using `$model->getScenario()`

Comment: @Pitchinnate Updated the question. I also verified the scenario: insert.

Comment: As you see, I have another own rules (functions) and they don't work too. The unique rule that works is the required... And I'm talking about server side validation.

Comment: @Pitchinnate Solved! It was a problem in my Controller. Thanks for your attention! Days ago I changed the model that received the input, but I forgot to change it in the Controller, so I was verifying with isset() something that didn't exist in $_POST. Now everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem in the Controller. Days ago I changed the model that received the input, but I forgot to change it in the Controller, so I was verifying with `isset()` something that didn't exist in `$_POST`. Now everything works perfectly.